# New line in constant error when using encoded HTML entities in binding expression attributes

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I often use binding expression attributes on my ASPX controls to build content including static text, resource strings and more dynamically strings load from anywhere.

Because I'm using some JavaScript to generate HTML from an attribute I was using some encoded HTML entities between some resource expressions on an binding expression attribute and I faced a weird behavior by Visual Studio.

Here is a basic example what happens:
[image: TextBox with HTML entities in a binding expression on the Text attribute]

It shows the "New line in constant" error, but it compiles and runs without problems. It only happens on binding expressions and only when using HTML entities on a string between some other code or not.

While I suspect to know why this happens, I'm looking for a further explanation. 
I found out that I can rather use the real characters than the HTML entities, because ASP.NET will convert the `<` to `&lt;` in any case. The problem is solved, because no HTML will be in the attribute, but I still wonder why this happens.

Using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 x64.

**EDIT: Please ignore the first comments on this question as the example and circumstances where a bit different when I created this question.**

Comment: VS parser used in editor for ASPX/CSHTML does not perform compilation to my knowledge... So sometimes it simply off. If you can't rewrite code to be simpler - ignore/disable. If curious - try to simplify code till VS is happy - and than add that info as an answer...

Comment: I suggest 1) Don't use fake attributes - they're not real, and 2) Use the `DataBinding` event to do this in codebehind, as it will be equivalent to what you're trying to do, but will be much cleaner.

Comment: BTW, If your codebehind is huge, you probably are not making your code modular enough. Can you factor any common functionality into other classes?

Comment: @AnnL. No, I already follow a strict n-tier design. The problem is the UI functionality in the code-behind is unique on this page, repeated things are already take off into separate classes. Of course with `#region`s it's not as hard to overview all of it, even with those `Data-Content` attributes set in code-behind. But in the project I got many controls I setup this way and it's simply easy to maintain, specially when I need a control that is similar, I can easily copy/paste from ASPX to ASPX and modify it (including the popover text that is loading from the `Data-Content` attribute).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov On me, it's not sometimes, it's always on those cases. I don't want to shorten my strong typed resource names, as I need them to clarify what string I get exactly. "If you can't rewrite code to be simpler - ignore/disable"? I'm not aware of any way to disable such things. Can you explain further?

Comment: Break it into user controls; Move the code to helper classes which you call from your code behind; Create a custom control that inherits from TextBox which implements your custom functionality... Reducing the size of your code behind is certainly possible.

Comment: To disable: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/disable-squiggly-or-wavy-lines-in.html (Options->Text->C#->Advanced->show live semantic errors")

Comment: @jessehouwing even when I build a new control for it, the length of the attribute will not change. I build together an unique text out of many resource strings and I prefer to do it on the markup.

Answer (score 2):

There are two binding expressions, `<%= %>` is used to assign the value and `<%# %>` is used to bind the value.

You should change

```
Text='<%# "&lt;&amp;&gt;" %>'
```

to

```
Text='<%= "&lt;&amp;&gt;" %>'
```

As `<%#` expects Bind or Eval method and not a constant string.

Comment: In my question I already say the problem is solved, there are many ways to do it the other way anyway. In my original problem case, I had to use this combined with variables, so only the code-behind solution would work, until I found out ASP.NET handles this problem in any case by converting `<` to `&lt;` automatically when using HTML on the attribute. So I left out my question to the WHY, not to the HOW ELSE part. Well it just seems to be a bug nobody can explain anyways.

Comment: Btw, I just came across this old question again, because it hit 1000 views today. I have to add something to your answer: `<%#` does not expect only Bind or Eval, it can be anything literally, even just a string or any call to a code-behind function. Thus you can use it to do things like `Text='<%# System.String.Format("This is a test {0}", this.anyString) + " asdfg" %>'`. Heck, you could even use conditional assignments in it.

Comment: @modiX did you see difference between `<%#` and `<%=` ?  one has `#` and other one has `=` at the end.

Comment: Are you even reading my comments, carefully? I know the difference between both and they are two entirely different things: `<%#` is a binding expression while `<%=` is an evaluation that is wrapped by `Response.Write()`, internally. So, solving my issue by using `<%=` does not work in every case as it won't work when I need to _bind_ data with string snippets. (And I'm not talking about Eval and Bind functions, we are not inside of data item binding right now!) And btw, both of your code samples end with `#>'` and this is even wrong, it has to end with `%>'`, always. Wasn't worth my rep tbh.